# Prepare data before go to the main view

Tags: c#, xaml, asynchronous, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

When the user touch the app icon, 
I want do these steps before user go to the main view

1. Fetch json string from URI
2. Use JArray.Parse to get the value
3. After all finish, go to the main view.

The problem is how can I prevent user to go to the main view
and put all the code
I tried to put it in Application_Launching method in the App.xaml.cs file

```
// Code to execute when the application is launching (eg, from Start)
// This code will not execute when the application is reactivated
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e) 
{
    // code here
}
```

But it doesn't prevent the program to go to the main view before the fetching finished.
And I found that actually in the MainPage.xaml, if I put this code like this

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    while(true) {} 
    // it will prevent the program to go to the main view, 
    // and will stick with the loading screen until this function reach its end
}
```

So I think, I can put the all the code here, when I finish the fetch, I will just break  the while and it will go to the main view automatically.

And I try, this is the code

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    bool isFetchFinished = false;

    ObservableCollection<PromoViewModel> Promos = new ObservableCollection<PromoViewModel>();

    WebClient client = new WebClient();

    client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, evt) =>
    {
        if (evt.Error == null)
        {
            // Retrieve the JSON
            string jsonString = evt.Result;

            JArray promos = JArray.Parse(jsonString);
            foreach (JObject promo in promos)
            {
                string name = promo["name"].Value<string>();
                string description = promo["description"].Value<string>();
                string img = promo["image"].Value<string>();

                Promos.Add(new PromoViewModel() { Name = name, Description = description, Img = img });
            }
          isFetchFinished = true;
          System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("finish fetch");
       }
    };

    // run 
    client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("the json url")); 

    while(true) {
        if(isFetchFinished) {
            App.ViewModel.LoadData(Promos); // pass value to main view model
            break; // after complete, break
        }
    }
}
```

I thought it would work, but it was not.
This is what I found,
The WebClient DownloadStringAsync won't run until the OnNavigatedTo function finished.
Because it's still waiting for the while loop to break and reach the end function.
And this

```
isFetchFinished = true; // will never executed
```

Resulting infinite loop. 
I think I put the fetch code in the wrong method. Where is the right place to put all of this?

Answer (score 3):

Ouch, you are doing it all wrong. First of all, you have to specify the starting page. If you want to download some data before navigating to it, you can create a special "download" page that is actually the first page navigated to when starting the application. And then, once the download is completed, you navigate to your main page. This is actually a replacement for the extended splash screen.

Also, never put `while (true)` in any UI code, that will simply freeze the application. Besides, if the application is frozen, you never get the chance to "unfreeze" it.

Comment: thanks brother, I came from iOS world, so that's iOS way to do that.
I don't know in windows phone, to download the data we must create a new view.
Can you show me a little syntax for that?

Comment: I didn't say that you *need* to create a new view, I said that you *can* create a different starting page - one that will display some "downloading..." text until data finished downloading and then automatically take user to the actual starting page.